# Create a 301 redirect using ISAPI Rewrite for IIS

Tags: iis, isapi-rewrite

I have created this one and it works,

```
RewriteRule shoppingcart.aspx ViewCart.aspx [NC,R=301]
```

I'm trying to get this to work,

```
RewriteRule search.aspx?advanced=1 AdvancedSearch.aspx [NC,R=301]
```

Not sure if i'm supposed to use a rewrite condition, or if the code i'm using will even work, I'm new to this so any help would be great

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's ISAPI_Rewrite 3 you are using, so the code should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^advanced=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule search\.aspx AdvancedSearch.aspx? [NC,R=301,L]
```